# ReCaptcha implementation still says "please verify that you're not a robot" even if it is checked

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have implemented ReCaptcha into a SweetAlert alert box. Checking the box to confirm I'm not a robot shows the SweetAlert warning to still verify that I am not a robot.

HTML code to launch the SweetAlert

```html
<form id="request_quote" method="POST" action="quoterequest.php">
<input type = hidden id = "...." value = "..."
<button id="quoteButton" class="mt-4 qbutton btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Request Print</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#request_quote").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Please enter your email',
      input: 'email',
      inputAttributes: {
        autocapitalize: 'off'
      },
      html: '<div id="recaptcha"></div>',
      didOpen: () => {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
          'sitekey': 'SITE_KEY'
        });
      },
      preConfirm: function () {
        if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please verify that you're not a robot`);
      }
     }
    }).then(function(result) {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
       ...rest of code
```

Code updated to reflect Aahan Agarwal response. Problem still persists.

I followed the documentation from the SweetAlert recipe site for adding ReCaptcha onto the alert itself, but something is going wrong with how I implemented it and currently the script is unable to be executed as the alert box still says to verify that I am a human.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly assuming your HTML code is not having the errors as you've posted in the question. Use this if not:

```html
<form id="request_quote" method="POST" action="quoterequest.php">
  <input type="hidden" id="...." value="..." />
  <button id="quoteButton" class="mt-4 qbutton btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Request Print
  </button>
</form>
```

Secondly, I think your `preConfirm` function is the cause of this. Try changing it to this:

```js
if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
  Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please verify that you're not a robot`);
}
```

*You could also do this in the `.then()` part, it would still work similarly.*

**UPDATE:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#request_quote").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Please enter your email',
      input: 'email',
      inputAttributes: {
        autocapitalize: 'off'
      },
      html: '<div id="recaptcha"></div>',
      didOpen: () => {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
          'sitekey': 'SITE_KEY'
        });
      }
    }).then((result) => {
      if (!result.isConfirmed) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please verify that you're not a robot`);
      } else {
        // Rest of the code..
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Implementation in `.then()` part, which worked for @couldnteverbeme. [JSFiddle link for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/mkd3auef/)

Comment: So to clarify I should get rid of the `preConfirm` and only have the if statement? Also thanks for including the bit of the HTML. That wasn't the problem I just forgot to copy the close tag on them

Comment: Update: Changed it to 
```      
preConfirm: function () {
 if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
    Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please verify that you're not a robot`);
   }
  }
}).then(function(result) {
``` 
and the problem still remains

Comment: Then it definitely has to do with `preConfirm` move the entire code in `.then()` like this: `if(!result.isConfirmed) =>Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please verify that you're not a robot`) else {}`

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8vygso1L/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkd3auef/